# Is $f(x,y)=\frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ continuous and differentiable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

Let $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} &\textrm{ if } (x,y)\neq(0,0), \\ 0 &\textrm{ if } (x,y)= (0,0).\end{cases} $$

I want to know: is $f$ is continuous? Are the partial derivatives exists at the origin? Is $f$ differentiable?

First, I tried some different paths to prove that $f$ is discontinuous, but none path lead me to it.

I found the partial derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{(y^2-x^2)|y|}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}},\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=\frac{x|y|(x^2-y^2)}{y(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}. $$

By doing $(x,y)=(0,t)$, the limit of the first partial derivative does not exist:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{t^2|t|}{t^3}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{|t|}{t} $$

Is this sufficient to  conclude that $f$ is not differentiable? What can I do?

Comment: Use AM GM inequality to prove $f$ is continuous. The partials do not have to be continuous for the function to be differentiable at a point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differentiability of $f(x)=\frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ in $(0,0)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542782/differentiability-of-fx-fracxy-sqrtx2y2-in-0-0)

Comment: @JingeonAn I did not understand the answer of this post. What exactly is that $\varphi$?

Comment: That is just a definition of the differentiability. I'll just write it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Continuity: $(x-|y|)^2=x^2+y^2-2x|y|\geq0 \iff \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\geq x|y|$
2. Partial Derivatives: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f((0,0)+h(1,0))-f(0,0)}{h}$ and it is analogous for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)$.
3. Derivability: Consider the linear application, $L$ , such that for any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}:L(x,y)=0$ then
   $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-L((x,y)-(0,0))}{||(x,y)-(0,0)||}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x|y|}{x^2+y^2}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understood the points 1 and 2. Could you elaborate the point 3?

Comment: I used the definition of derivability of  a multivariable function and so for any $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R^2}$ then $L_{(a,b)}(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(a,b)x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(a,b)y$.

Answer (score -3):

Firstly $f$ is continuous, indeed by polar coordinates we have

$$\frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=r\cos \theta |\sin \theta| \to 0$$

For differentiability by the definition we have

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0$$

and

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \frac{\frac{h|k|}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \frac{h|k|}{h^2+k^2} \neq 0$$

and therefore $f$ is not differentiable.

As noticed, we cannot conclude for differentiability from the discontinuity of partial derivatives.

Comment: You cannot conclude the limit at $(0,0)$ exists just by computing limits along the arrays. Polar coordinates are generally used for counter - examples.

Comment: @Invisible Do you mean that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$ is wrong? I don't think so, please reconsider your evaluation. Thanks

Comment: I don't think the result is wrong (AG inequality indicates it is indeed $0$), the deduction is, though.

Comment: @Invisible Then what is your point? Using polar coordinates is fine to show that limit exists also, and in this case it works fine.

Comment: [Limit $\frac{x^2y}{x^4+y^2}$ is found using polar coordinates but it is not supposed to exist.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/753381)

Comment: @Invisible The claim by the OP that $\lim_{r \to 0} \frac{r (\cos^2\theta\sin\theta)}{r^2\cos^4\theta + \sin^2\theta}=0$ is indeed wrong (the issue is in the denominator) but it doesn't mean that in general polar coordinates fail. In this case is totally fine indeed.

Comment: Refer also to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4727588/505767

Comment: You cannot consider limit along _some_ paths to conclude the limit exists and is equal along _every_ path. If the limit exists and is equal along every path, it will, of course, be so along arrays from the origin. I'm trying to explain three dowvotes you had gotten years ago.

Comment: @Invisible I'm not taking any path, by polar coordinates we consider all the possible ways. I don't think downvotes were given for that reason. Please refer also the the link I've given here.